# How to connect Virtual machine to LAN card other than HOST Card

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-workstation

I have two LAN cards on my server.
Server has 3 virtual Machines installed.
I used ICS on HOST OS 2008 server on second LAN card.

Now i want to use the internet of second LAN card in virtual machines to do some testing.
BUt VM automatically got internet from router not from my 2nd LAN card

How can i do that

Thanks

```
Vmware workstation 7.0
HOst:2008 server
VM windowxp VM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is point the specific VM to use your second NIC in the VM settings, you'll have to re-IP that VM obviously but it'll just work. If you want the VM to maintain the existing vNIC then simply create a second, point the new one at the second NIC and IP it appropriately paying particular attention to either your default gateway and/or static routes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what exact network configuration do you want... But try to go to menu Edit->Virtual Network Editor. There select VMnet0 (bridged) and change "Bridget to" from automatic to your 2nd network adapter.

Good luck!